# Cannot POST with content-type: application/json from angular to rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json, cors

So I am trying to send a POST request with Content-Type: application/json from angular to my rails backend. I get the following error in console:

> angular.js:12578 OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/api/student_create 404 (Not Found)

and

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/student_create. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8008' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Note the post request works properly when I use `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

It also works in Postman with the application/json Content-Type set in the header.

Angular Controller:

```js
.controller('View1Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {

  var data = {
    name: "name"
  };
  $http({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/student_create',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    data:data,
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response)
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  });

});
```

API controller (Rails):

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
     before_action :set_headers
     skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def set_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    end
  def create_student
    student = StudentUser.new
    student.name= params[:name]
    student.save
    render json: "test".to_json #temporary
  end
```

route: `post 'api/student_create' => 'api#create_student'`

Edit: frontend is on http://localhost:8008, backend is on localhost:3000

Comment: what is the size of the data you're trying to post?

Comment: It's just text. (the `data` object in the angular controller)

Comment: can you verify the object your sending is a valid json object

Comment: @alphapilgrim yeah it's valid, it's just the `data` object

Comment: The Rails code needs a route for an OPTIONS request that replies with CORS headers.

Comment: The Rails/your server config needs to be tweaked to accept OPTIONS request and also in your web server you need to set your CORS Header ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin') and not in your client code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I too faced this problem when i was interacting Rails with Angular. 
After lot of research i found gem 'rack-cors' which solved this issue. You can follow its documentation [here](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors). Rails by default doesn't allow cross origin resource sharing. So basically it handles cross origin requests nicely.

Steps:

Install the gem:

```
gem install rack-cors
```

Or in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
```

application.rb file

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # ...

    # Rails 3/4

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end

    # Rails 5

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, from [How to Configure CORS Accept Headers in Rails API Application](https://demisx.github.io/rails-api/2014/02/18/configure-accept-headers-cors.html)

> So, even if your consumer is on “localhost:3000” and your provider is on “localhost:3001”, the response will be neglected unless your web service sets a permissive CORS policy. This policy is defined by the provider setting specific CORS headers in HTTP response that a consumer app (e.g. a browser) destined to enforce. For example, configuring these headers:

```js
# in config / application.rb
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => 'http://my-web-service-consumer-site.com',
  'Access-Control-Request-Method' => % w {
    GET POST OPTIONS
  }.join(",")
}
```

Per site:

**Please note, that setting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*' is highly discouraged, unless you are providing a public API that is intended to be accessed by any consumer out there.**

Comment: You can try to use dataType: 'jsonp'. Try to search how to iplement jsonp for cross domain ajax calls.